# Grails - Bootstrapping test data fails

Tags: mysql, grails, bootstrapping

I'm encounter a strange error and I don't know how to fix it. I'm creating test entities in Bootstrap.groovy:

```
def init = { servletContext ->


    if (Environment.current != Environment.TEST) {
        servletContext.reloadId = new Date().getTime()  // for reloading css

        // create some insurance companies
        InsuranceCompany ozp = InsuranceCompany.findOrSaveWhere(code: "207", acronym: "OZP", name: "Oborová zdravotní pojišťovna zaměstnanců bank, pojišťoven a stavebnictví")
        InsuranceCompany vzp = InsuranceCompany.findOrSaveWhere(code: "111", acronym: "VZP", name: "Všeobecná zdravotní pojišťovna České republiky")
        InsuranceCompany vozp = InsuranceCompany.findOrSaveWhere(code: "201", acronym: "VOZP", name: "Vojenská zdravotní pojišťovna České republiky")
        Patient miladavrana = Patient.findOrSaveWhere(title: "JUDr", firstName: "Milada", lastName: "Vraná", RC: "0307080846", insuranceCompany: vozp,address: new Address(street: "5.Května", number: 568, city: "Korouhev", PSC: 16422))
        Patient jiristarecek = Patient.findOrSaveWhere(title: "", firstName: "Jiří", lastName: "Stareček", RC: "9457174705", insuranceCompany: cpzp,address: new Address(street: "Nad Schody", number: 180, city: "Velký Valtinov", PSC: 51521))
}
```

Actually the bootstrap file is quite longer, it has almost 1000 lines of test data. Everything works ok if I comment 2/3 of those data. When I have all of these data uncomment and grails is trying to create it, it fails:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000000262b036, pid=4152, tid=8016
#
# JRE version: 6.0_29-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.4-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# j  BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000d985800):  JavaThread "pool-7-thread-1" [_thread_in_Java, id=8016, stack(0x000000000bcf0000,0x000000000bdf0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000138c797cf

Registers:
RAX=0x000000000bdedd78, RBX=0x000000000bdedd78, RCX=0x00000000d9d1e488, RDX=0x00000000d9d0abff
RSP=0x000000000bdedd88, RBP=0x000000000bdeddb8, RSI=0x000000000d985800, RDI=0x000000000ee83ed0
R8 =0x0000000000000004, R9 =0x00000000d4b4e890, R10=0x000000006dfc4f80, R11=0x000000000ee83f38
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000000d9d1d8ce, R14=0x000000000bdee5b0, R15=0x000000000d985800
RIP=0x000000000262b036, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010287
```

this is part of the log the error generates. I'm using Grails 2.0.1 & MySQL 5.5.21 as a database. Anyone could hep or has this error before? Thank you very much.

Cheers,
Lojza

Comment: i think it is a Groovy problem. Groovy doesn't support big *.groovy files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing the heap allocation to your JVM through JAVAOPTS.

Comment: why don't you try breaking the code in the bootstrap into different classes and call them from the bootstrap. And when you're saving, do it in different transactions. Remember to flush when you save as well. I've known the JVM to handle big files but this seems to be either a groovy compiler or hibernate problem.

Comment: Thanks! You are absolutely correct! I use "withTransaction" and now it works like a magic!